# How to make a sitemap with Laravel

Tags: seo, google-search-console, sitemap, laravel

I am making a sitemap for a site made with Laravel and do not know if I am going the right way. I read an article from Google (https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/sitemaps/build-sitemap#general-guidelines, second item) saying that a sitemap will affect all the child directories from where the file containing the sitemap is located. But the problem is that I do not have a file *per se*, I have a controller that outputs an .xml when my route site.com/sitemap is called, so it's not an .xml, but rather a .php outputting an xml.

Google Search Console seems to have accepted this but I do not know if this is correct.

Thanks in advance for all the help. And sorry if this is more of a programming question.

Comment: You only need to generate a loop that outputs a posts list, showing the URL. Finally, check the sitemaps syntax and add the necessary tags to make a standard sitemap.

Comment: Ok, got it. Thank you a lot.

Comment: It's more accurate to say that a sitemap will affect all the child directories from where the sitemap's **path** is located. In other words, the URL that the (in this case generated) xml resource can be accessed at.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> saying that a sitemap will affect all the child directories from where the file containing the sitemap is located.

I'm not a fan of that wording. It's basically saying that a sitemap can only contain URLs that are at the same level or lower in the URL-path structure from where the sitemap is served from. Most sites serve their sitemap from the root directory so can contain URLs that cover the entire domain. However, a sitemap returned from `example.com/foo/sitemap` can contain `example.com/foo/bar` and `example.com/foo/bar/baz`, but not `example.com/bar` - which is outside of the URL-path tree.

Don't get hung up on the word "file". As far as the user-agent (eg. Googlebot) is concerned that makes the request, it does not know from the response whether the request mapped directly to a physical file or not.

And "directories" is referring to URL path segments, not physical directories on the underlying filesystem (which the user-agent making the request knows nothing about).

> But the problem is that I do not have a file per se, I have a controller that outputs an .xml when my route site.com/sitemap is called, so it's not an .xml, but rather a .php outputting an XML

That's perfectly fine. As mentioned above, the user-agent making the request can not tell the difference, since the HTTP response is likely to be the same.

*Aside:* The only potential issue might be if you are dynamically generating the sitemap on every request. This could be slow and resource intensive. The response should be cached server-side so it doesn't need to be generated on every request, only when your site has changed. (If the response is cached then you are "kind of" returning a "file", depending on how your caching works.)

Comment: That's a deeper look I didn't know, so thank you a lot for your knowledge. It was really helpful.